# Is it safe to check object reference in componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component connected to redux store and I have a code block like in this:

```
if (this.props.person !== nextProps.person) {
   ...
} else  {
  ...
}

...

MyComponent.propTypes {
  person: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Is it safe to check object reference in this way? Can I assume that in a reducer object reference will always change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe as long as your reducer is a **pure** function. To guarantee purity, those are the 3 most important things you should never do inside a reducer:

- Mutate its arguments (use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or the [object spread operator](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.md) to avoid mutations on objects)
- Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions
- Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

If your reducer satisfy all 3 conditions, any particular action dispatched that turned out to modify `person` property inside the state tree, will result in a new person `object`.

In that case, `this.props.person` and  `nextProps.person` would be two different objects and that object reference check would be correct. However if a particular action dispatched didn't modify `person` property inside the state tree, `this.props.person` and `nextProps.person` would still be the same object

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple reducer:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This is a normal part of redux - if your reducer is called with an unknown action, it returns the same state. In this case, `this.props.person === nextProps.person`, because the object reference has not changed.

If your code (your reducer) changes the reference to `person`, the reference will have changed in your component as well.